# Turtle on CustomTkinter is not plotting

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-turtle, customtkinter

Here is my code:

```
import customtkinter
import turtle

class App(customtkinter.CTk):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self.geometry(f"{600}x{600}")

    self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

    # create tabview
    self.tabview = customtkinter.CTkTabview(self)
    self.tabview.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
    self.tabview.add("Tab 1")
    self.tabview.add("Tab 2")
    self.tabview.add("Tab 3")

    self.tabview.tab("Tab 1").grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.tabview.tab("Tab 1").grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

    #turtle
    self.canvas = customtkinter.CTkCanvas(self.tabview.tab("Tab 1"))
    self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nesw")

    self.screen = turtle.TurtleScreen(self.canvas)

    self.turtle = turtle.RawTurtle(self.screen)

    self.turtle.forward(100) #this line cause error (not plotting) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

Upon running the code, it is throwing "TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()". I'm aware that the error happens when I start instructing the turtle to move, but I don't know why.

The turtle is showing on the screen but not moving (when the error line has been removed), though isn't centered relative to the window/screen (if someone can help in this as well).

[image]

Hopefully, someone can help me with both problems. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This appears to be an [issue with CustomTkinter](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/issues/1419), their `CtkCanvas.coords` method doesn't return anything. So use `tkinter.Canvas` instead

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error. Maybe customtkinter is not compatible with turtle. When I use standard tkinter for "Canvas" it works. But I also needed to put `self.update()`, because the movement is happening before the window is fully drawn and displayed:

```
import customtkinter
import turtle
from tkinter import Canvas

class App(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.geometry("600x600")

        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # Create tab view
        self.tabview = customtkinter.CTkTabview(self)
        self.tabview.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.tabview.add("Tab 1")
        self.tabview.add("Tab 2")
        self.tabview.add("Tab 3")

        self.tabview.tab("Tab 1").grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.tabview.tab("Tab 1").grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # Use standard Tkinter Canvas
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.tabview.tab("Tab 1"))
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nesw")

        self.screen = turtle.TurtleScreen(self.canvas)
        self.turtle = turtle.RawTurtle(self.screen)

        # Update the window before moving the turtle
        self.update()
        self.turtle.forward(1000)  # Move the turtle

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yesn't, it isn't an incompatibility it's just that the `CtkCavas.coords` method doesn't return the values it should be returning (See: https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/issues/1419)